# Using prime symbol from non-mathematical font in math mode

Tags: math-mode

Can I get the prime from Junicode (second and fourth line) to be used in math mode without having to use `\text{′}` every time?  That is, can I get the first line in the code (with an ascii apostrophe for prime) to produce the output of the 2nd and 4th?

After including the glyph with `setmathfont`, the prime is too small and high.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Junicode}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[
 range={"0370-"03FF,   % greek
 "0000-"003C,"003E-"007F},  % ascii range minus =
 ] {Junicode}

\begin{document}
$p'$\par
p′\par
$p′$\par
$p\text{′}$

\bigskip

\setmathfont[ range={"2032} ] {Junicode}

$p'$\par
p′\par
$p′$\par
$p\text{′}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are willing to type `′` instead of `'`?

Comment: @egreg, yes, it wouldn't be ideal, but if it produced the right output and there were no other way, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really portable, because it requires knowing that Junicode corresponds to mathgroup 4. However, `p''` will not give a very pretty double prime.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Junicode}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[
 range={"0370-"03FF,   % greek
 "0000-"003C,"003E-"007F},  % ascii range minus =
 ] {Junicode}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Umathcode`'="0 "4 "2032
  \Umathcode`′="0 "4 "2032
}

\begin{document}

$p'$\par
p′\par
$p′$\par
$p\text{′}$

\end{document}
```

[image]